# What is the "wheel" user in macOS/OS X?

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, user-accounts

I recently reinstalled iTunes and I noticed something peculiar.

The original version of iTunes has a user in the permissions known as `wheel` that is set to "Read Only".

I dragged this version of iTunes to the trash and installed a new copy, and when I look at the properties for iTunes it no longer says `wheel`, but rather just `admin`.

Here is a screenshot with the new version (left) and the old version (right):

[image]

What is the `wheel` user? How is it set (I can't seem to set it in the GUI)? Why would the permissions be different now?

It's not a problem, I'm just terribly curious.

Comment: I know this is old, but "wheel" is a group, not a user.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Some color:

Mac OS X has roots in BSD UNIX, a.k.a. the UNIX that came out of [UC Berkeley](http://berkeley.edu/).  They had a group of trusted people that could become superuser by using the `su` command.  So they coded their UNIX to only allow people in this specific group to become superuser using `su`.  They chose the groupname 'wheel', supposedly reference to other systems that had WHEEL, possibly a reference to being a '[big wheel](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/big+wheel)'

It's less important now that you have the GUI authorization popups and sudo.  You can use sudo without being in wheel group I believe.

As far as how to change to wheel, `chgrp` should be your friend, once you're root.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I'd add the note that wheel is group ID 0, just like root is user ID 0. You're right that, you don't have to be wheel to sudo. Mac OS X uses the group "admin" (group ID 80) as the default sudoers group. When you check the box to make an account an admin account, it gets added to the admin group.

Comment: chgrp operates on ownership files, newgrp changes the user to the group. newgrp enables  (read/write/execute) use of multiple group memberships, one at the time.

Comment: I just tried to sudo from a non-admin account and that did not work.  However... you can **su <admin-username>** and once you've done that you can sudo as you want.

Comment: If it doesn't work you might want to try `sudo -u <admin-user> <command>`. But for my experience the password to use is the one for the logged user rather than the password of the specified (or default) admin-user (supposedly *root* ?)

Answer (score 34):

`wheel` is the system administrator group in BSD, much like `root` is the system administrator user.

It is common to add `sudo` permissions to users in the `wheel` group.

Comment: Thanks Broam. Any idea how you would set a file to be part of the wheel group?

Comment: `chgrp wheel file`

Answer (score 12):

`wheel` is the group  used by OSX for the 'system' /Applications. It was present since at least 
**1989-03-13** in the [source of BSD Unix](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/blame/master/etc/group).

Whether the connotation is 'big wheel' or 'wheel of fortune' is unclear from my sources, but membership of wheel is special.

In OS X PAM is used to set the policy that `su(1)` will use.  In particular, by default
only users in the `admin` or `wheel` groups can switch to UID 0
(`root`).  This group requirement may be changed by modifying the
`pam_group` section of `/etc/pam.d/su`.  See `pam_group(8)` for details on
how to modify this setting.